# How can I find out how long an user input is in C?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
int sum=1;
char sent[50];
fgets(sent, sizeof(sent), stdin);
for(int i=0;i<=strlen(sent);i++){
    if(i==' '){
        sum++;
    }
}
scanf("%s", sum);


return 0;
}
```

What I want is to find how many words there are in the sentence. How can I find out how long the sentence is? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @david-c-rankin Thanks for the fast reply. The problem is that when I use my solution or yours, the console never stops asking me for input.

Comment: I decided to wrap it up in an answer and thanks to @chux it is now an improved answer to handle non-POSIX line ends or input greater than 49 characters.

Comment: @david-c-rankin chux Thank you very much! The idea to use a flag for the words was ideal. I didn't expect people here to be so fast and helpful. Thanks again :-)

Comment: Glad to help, good luck with your coding !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got a different approach to the problem here :
the idea is that 2 words in a sentence are separated by one or more spaces in between.

here is the altered code with my approach :-

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
 
int main()
{
    char sent[200];
    int sum = 1, i;
    fgets(sent, sizeof(sent), stdin);
    
    for (i = 0; sent[i] != '\0'; i++)
    {
        if (sent[i] == ' ' && sent[i+1] != ' ')
            sum++;    
    }
    printf("%d\n", sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If input is `" \n"`, this code reports 1 when there is no words.  Robust code would handle `" \n"` as 0 and `"abc xyz"`, `" abc xyz\n"`, `" abc  xyz"`, `"abc  xyz\n"` as 2.

Comment: Hmm... What happens if the user cancel input by generating a manual `EOF` with **Ctrl + d** (or **Ctrl + z** on windows)?

Comment: you both are right , looks like I overlooked the edge cases there 

Answer (score 3):

Continuing from the pseudo-code from @chux, an implementation would be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

#define MAXS 50         /* if you need a constant, #define one (or more) */

int main (void){

    int sum = 0, i = 0, inword = 0;     /* use inword as a flag, in/out word */
    char sent[MAXS];
    
    if (fgets(sent, sizeof(sent), stdin) == NULL) { /* read/VALIDATE input */
        fputs ("(user canceled input)\n", stderr);
        return 1;
    }
    
    while (sent[i]) {                   /* loop over each character */
        if (isspace(sent[i])) {         /* is the character a space? */
            inword = 0;                 /* set flag to false */
        }
        else {  /* otherwise */
            if (!inword)                /* if we were reading spaces, now in word */
                sum += 1;               /* increment sum */
            inword = 1;                 /* set flag true */
        }
        i++;                            /* increment loop counter */
    }
    
    printf ("whitespace separated words: %d\n", sum);
}
```

You keep a "state" variable `inword` that tracks the state of whether you are "in a word" reading characters, or before, between or after a word reading whitespace. This also ensures that leading whitespace, multiple-included whitespace and trailing whtiespace is ignored.

Answer (score 2):

> What I want is to find how many words there are in the sentence.

Set a flag indicating if parsing is in a word or not and count transitions from out to in

```
// Pseudo code
count = 0
in_word = 0
for each character `i` in `sent`
  if (sent[i] is a letter) 
    if (!in_word) count++
    in_word = true
  else
    in_word = false
print count
```

> How can I find out how long the sentence is?

Usually a simple `strlen(sent)` is sufficient.

More advanced ideas include discounting leading/trailing white-space.

Sample algorithm

```
// Pseudo code
for each character `i` in `sent`
  if character is not a space, break

offset = i
position_of_last_non_space = 0
for remaining characters `i` in `sent`
  if character is not a space
    position_of_last_non_space = i

sentence_length = position_of_last_non_space - offset + 1
```