# Counting words in file

Tags: c++

I'm trying to count the amount of records in a file, here's my code to begin with. It's in a 1 argument constructor

```
        CountWords(const char* filename) {
            ifstream file(filename);
            string temp;
            while (file >> temp) {
                words++;
            }
            file.close();
            name = new string[words];
        }
```

After counting the amount of records, it sets a new string array with the same size as the amount of words.

However, it doesn't seem to be accurate? The text file has 873335 words according to countwordsfree.com, but the program shows 901326. How is this possible?

Is the ' ' space default as the delimiter in this case? Or would I have to add that manually and if so how?

Comment: 901326 words is a lot of text, have you tried reducing your sample so that differences are more obvious? the `>>` operator splits by whitespace, while countwordsfree seems to split by some punctuation as well (try `word:word` for example)

Comment: You are counting *whitespace* separated words, but without seeing more you should set `words = 0;` at the beginning of the function (unless that is done elsewhere). You have ~ 3% difference in your count verses the expected count. That could be due to having non-words (like `"1."` at the beginning of the line) or having strings like `"ishkabibble"` (yiddish?) . There can be hyphenated words broken by a newline that can cause you to count 2 for 1, etc.. It will all boil down to what your word recognition criteria is. (which you haven't shared)

Comment: The `name = new string[words];` makes no sense at all unless you are expecting to capture all the words in an allocated block of strings called `name` -- which you should have done when reading them rather than forcing yourself to read-twice (one of the least efficient things to do)

Comment: Also *"I'm trying to count the amount of* ***records*** *in a file"* -- that is a bit ambiguous with your title as "records" implies *lines* not *words*.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Sorry for the confusion, i mean words in all cases. I have words set to 0 elsewhere, and i do plan on capturing all the words in another string, however i can change the way that works. I want the count to go up for every whitespace. Would it be okay to use get(), go through each character and increment the counter whenever it reads a space?

Comment: Yes, you can use `.get()`, but you have to keep a flag to indicate when you are in a word reading characters, or between words reading spaces, so you count multiple intervening spaces as a single series of whitespace. What you are doing is the correct way to count *whitespace* separated words -- but there something else going on like hyphenation, etc.. causing your count to be off. Using `.get()` would be similar to [How can I find out how long an user input is in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64180443/3422102)

Answer (score 0):

You can not add delimiter to istream object.
And you did not initialize words to zero.

```
void CountWords(const char* filename) {
            ifstream file(filename);
            words = 0;
            string temp;
            while (file >> temp) {
                if(temp == "\n" || temp == "\r" || temp == "\t") continue;
                words++;
            }
            file.close();
            name = new string[words];
        }
```

Comment: `temp` will never be `"\n\r\t"` as `>>` ignores *whitespace* and each of those characters is ... *whitespace*. (you are thinking about *character-oriented* input like with `file.get()` instead of *whitespace* separated string input -- which may not be a bad way to do it depending on what the criteria for a "word" is...)